# Export pipe-delimited data with progress db

Tags: dump, progress-database

I've been handed a task where we need to dump specific tables in a progress database (10.2B) to pipe-delimited flat files (50+ tables) and send them to a third party for analysis every week.

Looking at the `sqldump` command it seems it only supports comma delimited or quoted... but I have data in these tables with both commas and quotes.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok with writing some code:

```
OUTPUT TO VALUE("filename.d"). 

FOR EACH table-name:
EXPORT DELIMITER "|" table-name.
END.

OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

It's possible to write something that's more automated than this if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Data Administration tool > export data > text
choose table(s) >next
output file - remove .txt extension
choose all fields/records radio buttons >ok
Field delimiter, remove the " - field should be empty
Field separator, remove comma, enter the pipe,
click OK. 
Output will be created in the start in directory

Comment: Hmmm... sounds like this thing has a gui.  Unfortunately, I'm on a Linux system.  Is there a command line equivalent?

Comment: Digging in old posts here... But there's actually a gui even if your on a command prompt. A character based gui that mimics the looks of the graphical Data Admin tool. The binary you should be looking for is `INSTALLPATH/bin/pro`. In the Tools menu you will find Data Administration. (The menu is usually accessed with the F3-key).